# Setting a new IP as a subfolder of an existing IP

Tags: apache, proxy, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I'm pretty new to Apache configurations... is the following possible?

I have 2 separate web servers, each hosting a different application - totally separate.

My main application is under the domain `www.example.com`. What I want to do is set the other server's domain to something like `www.example.com/newapp` so that when users go to this URL, they will be redirected to the 2nd server (which is a totally different domain/IP/virtualhost); pages under this second server's url will always be `www.example.com/newapp/xxxx`.

**NOTE:** there is nothing matching this directory structure under the first, main application.

Basically, the `www.example.com/newapp/` application is completely separate, but I want users to think its actually the same website.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the first server handling all example.com requests to proxy requests to the new server when a request for example.com/newapp is received. This will cost you bandwidth on both sides, beware of that.

Using ProxyPass & ProxyPassReverse should suffice. If you want hyperlink conversion as well, you need to use mod_proxy_html

`ProxyPass /newapp/ http://xx.xx.xx.xx/newapp`

`ProxyPassReverse /newapp/ http://xx.xx.xx.xx/newapp`

mod_proxy_html: http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
UseCanonicalName Off 
ProxyPass /newapp/ http://xx.xx.xx.xx/ 
ProxyPassReverse /newapp/ http://xx.xx.xx.xx/ 
Include /etc/apache2/conf/railsapp.conf 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response .. Ive tried putting these directives directly in the VirtualHost section of httpd.conf, but do not get the desired proxy action -- please see updated comment

Comment: it did not give any errors in /var/log/errors.log either ... actually it did not seem to affect anything.  did i miss something? thx

Comment: If you didn't get the proxy action, what else did you get on visitng /newapp? Just 404 not found? I just checked apache documentation and all the examples have a trailing slash at the path which is to be proxied, not sure why, but I have updated the post. Try and report back. :-)

Comment: Thanks, tried it ... same result - just a 404 w nothing in the logs. going to try and see if mod_proxy is on my system ( i guess it should be)  also, im using Phusion Passenger, if that makes any diff

Comment: mod_proxy is definitely on, otherwise you'd have got undefined directive error while apache loads the configuration. Phusion Passenger is just an apache module to support ruby, it shouldn't be interfering with mod_proxy. Also, change LogLevel to debug and see what you see in error log, I suspect some other problem like firewall, etc

Comment: could not solve this - anyways, i just switched back to having both apps on the same server :(  at least save on some EC2 server time!